# Scrollable Control in ScrollViewer WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I made a control for selecting Date. you can increase or decrease Day,Month or year
just by Scrolling MouseWheel.
but when I put this control in ScrollViewer MouseWheel will scroll ScrollViewer and MyControl not work properly.
I have searched a lot to prevent ScrollViewer from handling MouseWheel but I couldn't.

this is my Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
         some other elements...

            <controls:DateTimeSelect Width="400" Value="{x:Static system:DateTime.Now}"/>

         some other elements...
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not work properly"? Is scrolling not happening at all? Or is it not having any smooth scroll? DateTimeSelect looks like a custom control? How does your view looks like? Can u share those details?

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for `PreviewMouseWheel` event from`ScrollViewer` and forward it to your `DateTimeSelect` control.

This code directs the `PreviewMouseWheel` event within the first ScrollViewer:

```
private void HandlePreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ScrollViewer && !e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
            eventArg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent;
            eventArg.Source = sender;
            var parent = ((Control)sender).Parent as UIElement;
            parent.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
        }
    }
```

For more information, see https://serialseb.com/blog/2007/09/03/wpf-tips-6-preventing-scrollviewer-from/.

To know more about how to use it in your case, further information about `contol: DateTimeSelect` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your answers.
I tried so many ways but I realized that ScrollViewer not working as expected.
so I made a new project and copied all files from old project to new one step by step
and after each change I checked whether scrollerViewer woks properly or not.
I am using DevExpress MVVM framework so I have to create and show mainWindow in Bootstarpper and remove StartupUri from App.xaml.
I realized that this is where I have problem, every time I set StartupUri and and let App class to show MainWindow nothing is wrong but as I Creating MainWindow manually and show ScrollViewer catches MouseWheel and preventing its children to hadnling it.